# chemfig: atom vertically shifted when using \Charge

Tags: chemfig

When using `\Charge`the atom is shifted vertically

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{-C(-[2])(-[6])-\Charge{20=\|,110=\|}{O}(-[:290]H)} \qquad \chemfig{-C(-[2])(-[6])-O(-[:290]H)} 
\end{document}
```

[image: visualization of vertical shift]

How to avoid this?

Comment: The \charge macro places the 〈charges〉 out of the bounding box while \Charge places them into the bounding box. (manual)

Comment: this is the solution